# How can I check website security for free?

Tags: php, security

I've heard that there are some free applications that will check the vulnerability of a PHP website, but I don't know what to use.  I'd like a free program (preferably with a GUI) for Windows that will analyze my site an give me a report.

Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Just one of the many, but a newer one (compared to the age of the question): [OWASP Zed Attack Proxy Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are only certain security holes you can check for with any program. You can check your PHP configuration, Apache configuration, passwords, common bugs, etc. but you can't really check programatically for logic errors which might cause security holes.

Your best bet would be to do a thorough code review of the website. Or, better yet, have several other people do a thorough code review of the website, looking for security holes.

Answer (score 28):

[Top 10 Web Vulnerability Scanners](http://sectools.org/web-scanners.html) from Insecure.org (listing from 2006).  Their number one, Nikto2, can be found [here](http://www.cirt.net/nikto2).

Comment: Another free one released since then is Google's Skipfish http://code.google.com/p/skipfish/

Comment: Skipfish zip file is empty

Comment: @Erwinus just tried downloading it and it worked for me

Answer (score 8):

[Netsparker Community Edition](http://www.mavitunasecurity.com/communityedition/) does that and it's free (GUI + Windows).

Comment: I've used netsparker before. It has great usability.

Answer (score 4):

I recently found [Detectify](https://detectify.com) which seems to make a decent scan and has nice UI. They work on donation basis which means you should decide how much you can spend.

> We cover OWASP Top 10. That means we find a wide variety of flaws, including SQL, LDAP, XPATH and NoSQL injections, Cross Site Scripting flaws, broken session management, remote code and command execution, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but since you specifically asked for easy to use and not-too-technical scanners, take a look at [Golem Technologies website security scanner](https://www.golemtechnologies.com) - the full scan isn't free, but they have a demo scan which checks about 10% of a site and will catch a lot of the common vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2):

This is another one, but as previously stated, nothing beats a professional eye-over:

http://www.websitedefender.com